# Telecom Services Database

Tags: data-request, api, telecom

Does anyone know where can I find the datasets for Telecom Services like below

```
Fixed line voice
IP voice services
Internet access services
Ethernet services
Private IP services
Very-high bandwidth services
Legacy data services
Consumer pay TV services
Mobile services
Multiplay service packages
Cloud connectivity services
Low-power wide area
```

Any resources/references would be highly appreciated.